# PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: time zone "Central Time (US & Canada)" not recognized - Error updating Rails timezone in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, timezone, rspec-rails

I'm trying to update a time zone as part of a spec to test one of the scenarios which seems to be an edge case that's not working.

I have a `timezone` attribute for one of the tables and its of type `String`, however when  I try something like the below in the rails console, I'm getting:

1. `a.timezone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"` (I especially wanted to convert the timezone to `CDT`, hence used: "Central Time (US & Canada)")

Error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  time zone "Central Time (US & Canada)" not recognized

I'm wondering if this has to do with Postgres & if I need to make any changes around that to accept the CDT timezone?

Answer (score 0):

First of all select a valid timezone format using this query.

```
SELECT
    name,
    abbrev,
    utc_offset,
    is_dst
FROM pg_timezone_names;
```

Then you can either use the timezone function for the conversion or use a datatype that stores the timezone info e.g.

```
postgres=# create table test(ts_tz timestamp with time zone, just_var varchar);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into public.test values (now(),now());
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# show time zone;
 TimeZone
----------
 Etc/UTC
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from test;
            ts_tz             |           just_var
------------------------------+------------------------------
 2023-05-03 08:43:28.96206+00 | 2023-05-03 08:43:28.96206+00
(1 row)

postgres=# select ts_tz at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' from test;
         timezone
---------------------------
 2023-05-03 01:43:28.96206
(1 row)

postgres=# select timezone('America/Los_Angeles', to_timestamp(just_var,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')) from test;
      timezone
---------------------
 2023-05-03 01:43:28
(1 row)
```